# Progress bar with queued files in d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add a progress bar (or whatever suggesting progress) when loading multiple files with d3.queue.js

I looked at this for instance
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941

However, when I defer loading the csv, I can't access the progress events (there is only one very large file, so if the progress only apply to one file, that's ok):

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, filepath1)
  .defer(d3.csv, filepath2)
  .defer(function(f) {
    d3.csv(filepath3)
      .on("progress", function() {
        console.log(d3.event.loaded) // this never updates
        var i = d3.interpolate(progress, d3.event.loaded / total);
        d3.transition().tween("progress", function() {
          return function(t) {
            progress = i(t);
            foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
            text.text(formatPercent(progress));
          };
        });
      })
      .get(function(error, data) {
        f(error, data);
      })
  })
```

Any thoughts on why I can't use the `.on("progress")` call? How else could I do it?

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sEEl0PIz3R3Lx094OJYt?p=preview), the progress calls fire from a `.defer`.

Comment: @Mark Thanks! What I was trying to do was to use my third file (I actually have six) to draw the progress wheel. I tried again this morning and it actually worked! Not sure what I did differently, but thanks for having a look at it :)